# 0 test classes found message appears after running package with 5 tests

Tags: java, testng

0 test classes found message appears after running package with 5 tests.

"No Tests were found" error appears when trying to run Package with 5 tests. ( TestNG)

```
0 test classes found in package 'smoketest'

Process finished with exit code 255
Empty test suite.
```

Foundation package runs fine. But "smoketest" returns 0 test classes found.

[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CaGp.png)

[modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgRAz.png)

```
package smoketest;


import com.pageobjects.*;
import config.AndroidGestures;
import config.DesiredCapabilitiesSetup;
import config.LogIn;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;


public class CardManagementTest {
    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    private AOWebClient aoWeb;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public CardManagementTest(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver, AOWebClient aoWeb) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.aoWeb = aoWeb;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public CardManagementTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer();
    }

    @Test
    public void cardManagementTest() throws InterruptedException {
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        AOWebClient aoWebClient = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.getAOWeb();
        HamburgerMenuList ham = new HamburgerMenuList(driver,aoWeb);
        ProfileInfoScreen profile = new ProfileInfoScreen(driver);
        CardManagementScreen card = new CardManagementScreen(driver, aoWeb);
        LogIn logIn = new LogIn(driver, aoWebClient);
        HeaderMenu header = new HeaderMenu(driver, aoWeb);
        AndroidGestures gesture = new AndroidGestures(driver);

        String month = "Aug";
        String year = "2020";
        String cardNumber = "4444333322221111";
        String cvv = "123";
        String expectedCardLastDigits = cardNumber.substring(12);

        logIn.loginWithYourCredentials("c1@mailinator.com", "testtest");
        header.clickHamburgerButton();
        ham.waitForHamMenuScreentoLoad();
        ham.accountButtonClick();
        profile.waitForProfileScreenToLoad();
        profile.cardManagementClick();
        card.waitForCardManagementScreenToLoad();
        softAssert.assertTrue(card.noSavedCardLabelAppear(), "No saved Card Label Does Not Appear");
        card.setAddCardButtonClick();
        card.cardNumberInput(cardNumber);
        card.cardExpClick();
        card.monthPickerWheel.click();
        card.selectAugustMonth();
        card.yearPickerWheel.click();
        card.selectYear2020();
        card.dateSubmitButton.click();
        card.cardCVVClick();
        card.cardCVVInput(cvv);
        card.cardSaveClick();
        card.waitForCardManagementScreenToLoad();
        softAssert.assertEquals(card.creditCardGetLast4Digits(), expectedCardLastDigits, "Actual Credit Card and Expected Credit card numbers are not the same");
        //Assertion that Credit Card was added 4 last digits
        card.deleteCreditCardButtonClick();
        //Assertion that "Delete this saved card" message appear
        softAssert.assertTrue(card.confirmDeleteLabelAppear(), "Delete confirmation screen did not appear");
        card.cancelDeleteCardButtonClick();
        softAssert.assertEquals(card.creditCardGetLast4Digits(), expectedCardLastDigits, "Actual Credit Card and Expected Credit card numbers are not the same");
        card.deleteCreditCardButtonClick();
        card.confirmdeleteCardButtonClick();
        card.waitForNoSavedCardLabelLoad();
        softAssert.assertTrue(card.noSavedCardLabelAppear(), "No saved Card Label Does Not Appear");
        header.backButtonClick();
        profile.waitForProfileScreenToLoad();
        softAssert.assertTrue(profile.profileScreenAppear(), "Profile View Page Does Not Appear");
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.closeApp();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Gradle :

```
group 'ao-core-android'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5


test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'testng.xml'
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    //compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.12'
    //compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.0.0'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.1'
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'externalLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('./lib-test-tools-1.4.0.jar')
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke Test">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="config.CustomLogger" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="SmokeTest">
        <packages>
            <package name="smoketest"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: please show us test class code.

Comment: Did you annotate the test methods with `@Test` ?

Comment: i added test class code.

Comment: It runs perfectly one by one, but it does not runs as a package.

Comment: what about creating a separate class with @TestSuite and including the test class reference?

Comment: It was working before.
Probably i made a Refactor of 
"@Test" method and somehow i cannot run anymore my tests from folder. 
I was needed to chance "@Test" method name.

Comment: If in TestNG.xml i point to run test folder - it does not see any tests.
If i point to run test one by one ( in TestNG.xml) it runs whole folder.

Comment: Please add your run configuration. Do you use gradle or embedded IJ TestNG runner?

Comment: I updated main question.

Comment: When i trying to use Gradle or TestNG.xml file to run i`m getting this issue.
When i run test one by one it runs perfectly, and if in TestNG.xml i will point each test one by one instead of pointing to package it will run aswell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<test name="Email">
    <classes>
    <class name="<package name>.<class name>"/> 
    </classes>
</test>
```

Similar to the above thing we need to have the class inside the test then only the test suit will execute it.